# how do i find the direction of the part of a character in roblox lua?

Tags: lua, roblox

i am adding a belt to my character, but whenever i add the belt it faces in one direction no matter the orientation of my character. How do i make it so the direction my humanoid root part is facing is the same direction that the belt is facing?

Answer (score 0):

A [humanoid's root part](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/understanding-root-parts) is just a regular [Part](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Part), and all Parts have a [CFrame](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/BasePart/CFrame) that represents their position and orientation in 3d world space. All [CFrames](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/CFrame) have a LookVector that points in their forward direction.

If you are adding a belt to a Character model, I would recommend using a part within the model and using its CFrame as a starting point, then offsetting it accordingly.

For example :

```
-- access the character model in the workspace
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAppearanceLoaded:Connect(function(character)

        -- DEBUG : wait for player to stop falling
        wait(2)
        
        -- choose a starting point
        local hips = character:WaitForChild("LowerTorso", 10)
        
        -- create a belt
        local belt = Instance.new("Part")
        belt.Name = "Belt"
        belt.Size = Vector3.new(2,1,2)
        
        -- position the belt on the player's character
        -- NOTE - EXPERIMENT WITH CHANGING THESE VALUES TO ADJUST THE POSITION AND ROTATION
        local positionOffset = CFrame.new(Vector3.new(0, 0, 0))
        local rotationOffset = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(0), math.rad(0), math.rad(0))
        belt.CFrame = hips.CFrame * positionOffset * rotationOffset
        
        -- weld the belt to the player
        local weld = Instance.new("WeldConstraint", belt)
        weld.Part0 = belt
        weld.Part1 = hips
        
        -- DEBUG : color the front of belt to make sure that it is oriented correctly
        local surface = Instance.new("SurfaceGui", belt)
        surface.Adornee = belt
        surface.Face = Enum.NormalId.Front
        local frame = Instance.new("Frame", surface)
        frame.Size = UDim2.fromScale(1, 1)
        frame.Position = UDim2.fromScale(0, 0)
        frame.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(0, 0, 1)
        
        -- put the belt into the world
        belt.Parent = character
    end)
end)
```